# 500 internal server error using jquery and ajax in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am building edit post system using jquery and ajax in laravel 5.2. When i click on save changes button in my bootstrap modal, the following error is displayed:

> Error: POST http://localhost:8000/edit 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> send @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4
>
> ajax @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4   (anonymous function) @ myplace.js:24
>
> dispatch @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3
>
> r.handle @ jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3

js code:

```
$('#modal-save').on('click' , function() {

 $.ajax({

 method : 'POST' ,
 url : url ,
 data: { body: $('#post-body').val(), postid: '' , _token: token }})

.done(function(msg) {

console.log(msg['message']);

    });
  });
```

Included in view file:

```
    <script>
    var token='{{ Session::token() }}';
    var url='{{  route('edit') }}' ;
  </script>


 <script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" ></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="src/js/myplace.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Internal Server Error` is your server's way of telling you you should read it's logfiles. That's the only place where you can find useful debugging information.

Comment: @Oldskool my log file : http://laravel.io/bin/E31Qy

Comment: Looks like your CSRF token is invalid. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Comment: @Oldskool ya ty , but i have already implemented the method but same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have problems with our csrf token. Before making your ajax calls just change your ajax setup and put the token in every header you sent via ajax. This should fix your error.

First add a meta tag

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then adjust ajax setup

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
});
```

or even simpler

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
```