# Laravel form post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to post a form with ajax. I get a errror in my console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have a form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'uren','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
//inputs here etc..
{{ Form::button('Add', array('class' => 'btn btn-btn send-btn')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.send-btn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uren',
            type: "post",
            data: {
                'werk':             $('input[name="werk"]').val(),
                'starttijd':        $('input[name="starttijd"]').val(),
                'eindtijd':         $('input[name="eindtijd"]').val(),
                'omschrijving':     $('input[name="omschrijving"]').val(),
                '_token':           $('input[name="_token"]').val()},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In route(web.php):

```
Route::post('uren', 'User\UrenController@store');
```

In controller:

```
public function store() {

    if (\Request::ajax()) {

        if(Request::input('omschrijving') != '') {
            $omschrijving = Request::input('omschrijving');
        }else{
            $omschrijving = '';
        }

        DB::table('uren')->insert(
            [
                'userID' => Auth::user()->id,
                'datum' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                'projectID' => Request::input('werk'),
                'starttijd' => Request::input('starttijd'),
                'eindtijd' => Request::input('eindtijd'),
                'omschrijving' => $omschrijving
            ]
        );

    }

}
```

I think I need to do something with the **csrf_token** token. To pass the 500 error. But how can I do that?

[UPDATE]
I added the token and I can send the token back and show the token in a `alert`. But when I add `DB::table....` it still gives me the 500 error

[COMPLETE]
The problem was my query.. a field was empty but it needs to be a string. I solved it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have now the token in my codes. I can alert the token that has been send to my controller with the Ajax request. But I still get the 500 error when I add the `DB::table code`

Comment: Just FYI, your if statement (Request::input('omschrijving') != '') is pointless. Your checking if the request input is an empty string and if it is then make your `$omschrijving` an empty string anyway. Also you can supply a default to `Request::input()` as the second param i.e. `'omschrijving' => Request::input('omschrijving', '')`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want CSFR middleware you can disable that in laravel 5:

To disable CSFR protection: 
go to this file:

```
   app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

You can disable for all post request or for particular route.
For more info xfer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection

OR

just pass another parameter in your data `"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my post. I send the token to my controller and can show it with a `alert` in the `success` of my ajax. But I still get the 500 error when I add the `DB:table...`

Comment: Please provide more details about error, please use try catch or set error reporting on to get more details about error

Comment: The error in my console: _POST http://localhost:8080/urenreg/public/uren 500 (Internal Server Error)_. I'm gonna try if I can get more info..