# Laravel- Token Mismatch Exception on Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, ajax-request

Like in the headline mentioned I get a token Mismatch Exception if I try to do `ajax` request.

The strange this is, I do have the `csrf_token` in my code.

In my `<head> ... </head>` i have added this line: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

And above the ajax code I've got this code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

But I also tried to put the code into my ajax code. Like this:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/sendAnswer",
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                data: {'question': question, 'answer': answer},
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
        });
```

And I also tried this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/sendAnswer",
        data: {'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}", 'question': question, 'answer': answer},
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
});
```

Now everything I've tried, gave me a Token Mismatch Exception back.

The Javascript code you see is at the very bottom of my page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request)

Comment: the code that helped this guy in your duplicate link is allready in my code. Thats why it is so strange. I've got everything I need for the request.

Comment: Try/Check 3rd answer from this link! May be it works for you!

Comment: I've tried that but it still gave me the same error :/

Comment: Alternatively you can add `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }` if the token is being stored as a cookie

Comment: Check the rendered HTML source - is the token really there in your JS?  Check browser devtools, is _token properly POSTed?

Comment: I had a similar issue, turns out to be an extra empty line before the <?php tag, check if there is any file in the routes folder, config folder, and controllers, also check if the response returning from the Ajax has that extra empty line.