# create post method and passing id with ajax and laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6, ajaxform

I'm trying to add ajax to my method laravel. This method is creating a reply under a discussion page. It was working before the Ajax, now i want to add the ajax to make the reply very fast ! i'm stack because i tried a lot of method to pass the $id (discussion_id) but no one works !

i'm using laravel 5.6

my route is :

```
Route::post('/discussion/reply/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'DiscussionsController@reply',
    'as' => 'discussion.reply'
]);
```

my function controller is :

```
   public function reply($id)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'reply' =>'required',
    ]);

    $d = Discussion::find($id);

    $reply = Reply::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'discussion_id' => $id,
        'content' => request()->reply
    ]);


    Session::flash('success', 'Votre réponse a été enregistrer avec success');

    //return redirect()->back(); // this is what i was doing doing before the ajax



    return response()->json(['success'=>'réponse ajouter']);
}
```

my JavaScript Ajax :

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/discussion/reply/",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        reply: jQuery('#reply').val(),
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
              jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, value){
                jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                jQuery('.alert-danger').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
            });
        }
    });
```

and finally my form blade html :

```
<form action="{{ route('discussion.reply', ['id' => $d->id]) }}" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="reply">Laisser une réponse...</label>
                            <textarea name="reply" id="reply" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn pull-right" id="submit">Répondre</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: You are calling the wrong url in the javascript `url: "/discussion/reply/"`

Comment: i call this url : {{ URL::route('discussion.reply', ['id' => $d->id]) }} but i got errors in my js file !

Comment: is your script in the same blade.php file or is it in separated js file?

Comment: yes my script is loaded and everything work i have only the problem to figure out how the url will be in the ajax method

Comment: As you said your script is loaded then you should be able to fix your error. it the error related with `{{ }}` then convert it to `<?php ?>`, if `$d` not defined the put the right one. Any level of developer should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Secondly as this is a post req, you have to pass the `csrf_token` too otherwise the req won't reach the controller method

Comment: the problem is in the js, i pass the csrf_token : this is the error i got in my console : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code .test please:

Ajax :

```
<script>
_token="{{csrf_token()}}";

$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("{{route('discussion.reply',['id' => $d->id])}}",
        {

            reply: $('#reply').val(),
            _token:_token
        },
        function(data, status){
            if(status=="success")
            {
                alert('success')
            }
            else
            {
                alert('show error')
            }

        });
});
</script>
```

`DiscussionsController` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class DiscussionsController extends Controller
{
    public function reply(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'reply' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
        }


        $d = Discussion::find($id);

        $reply = Reply::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'discussion_id' => $id,
            'content' => request()->reply
        ]);


        return response()->json(['success'=>'réponse ajouter'],200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you encountered an ‍‍`Error`?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ! the problem is in the url : i think here my problem with this url: '{{url::route('discussion.reply')}}',

Comment: where you use `url::route('discussion.reply')` . can you show your code  ?

Comment: you can use `"{{route('discussion.reply',['id' => $d->id])}}"`

Comment: i got : app.js:1 POST http://channel/discussion/route(%22/discussion/reply/%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is because the value of the variable ‍‍`$d->id`, is empty in your code.can you show your `get` route?

Comment: Do i need got route for this ? Im using a post here !

Comment: Do you pass the `$d` variable to View?

Comment: Yes ! As i said the problem is in my JavaScript

Comment: can you append your `routes` in your question?

Comment: I mean the Route that load  your 'view'

Comment: Its a get roote ! Return a /discussion/{slug}