# Unable to make ajax request in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.6

I am trying to delete a record using ajax from an alert button but nothing is done. Here is what i have so far
The button

```
<button type="button" value="{{$announcement->id}}" id="close-alert" class="close" data-url="{{ route('member.postDeleteAnnouncement', ['id' => $announcement->id]) }}" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

app.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#close-alert').click(function() {
    var url =$('#close-alert').data('url');
    ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        success: function(){
                console.log('data sent');
            },
    });
});
```

});

and my controller action

```
public function postDeleteAnnouncement ($announcement_id)
{
    $user = \Sentinel::getUser();
    $member = $user->member;

    $member->announcements()->detach($announcement_id);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

here is the route code

```
Route::post('/announcement/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'SiteController@postDeleteAnnouncement', 'as' => 'postDeleteAnnouncement']);
```

Comment: Any error you are facing? means which error came while doing this?

Comment: @AjayM. no error whatsoever

Comment: your route code?

Comment: @AjayM. route code added

Comment: Make `console.log` for your `url` ... and use `var url = $(this).data("url")`. for POST requests, I'd suggest to use `data: { inputName: value }` in `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Did u post the CSRF token? It this form or just button?

```
var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
```

and pass together with other data.

```
data: { _token:_token , etc:etc }
```

worth to try

Comment: It is just a button

Comment: sorry i thought ur's form , anyway read here u must pass CSRF token "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request/39530688"

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token is missing in your ajax request, and which is mandatory for every post type request. Use it like:

```
$.ajax({
...
method: 'post',
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
...
});
```

and inside your blade view, use:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Comment: I have added the CSRF token but it's still not posting