# Laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException Ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I get a TokenMismatchException error only when I submit a form with an ajax call? If I don't use an Ajax call I don't get the error.

What is causing this?

Laravel 5.4

I have this in the head of my `app.blade.php`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

My `ajax.js`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // storing comments
    $('#storeComment').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/comments',
            data: {},
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I also use the bootstrap.js that automatically registers the value of the  csrf-token meta tag with the Axios HTTP library. As explained in the Laravel documentation.

Controlle Method:

```
public function store(CommentRequest $request)
{
    $comment = Auth::user()->comments()->save(new Comment($request->all()));

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'comment' => $comment
    );

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: have you sended csrf token in data field

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I don't think this is necessary since I store it in the meta tag as explained in the laravel documentation?

Comment: But you havent used `axios` here. you use `jquery`

Comment: Because `automatic csrf injection` is in axios, not in jquery.

Comment: @Michael you're correct.  The ajaxSetup call should set the header appropriately for you.  I think you may have an underlying issue with your sessions.

Comment: there is no ajax setup in this question. read the question again. He explicitly says "I also use the bootstrap.js that automatically registers the value of the csrf-token meta tag with the Axios HTTP library. As explained in the Laravel documentation."

Comment: @TharakaDilshan the op removed it, he had the line mentioned here in the first revision https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: of course i saw earlier version of this question. but it has nothing to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Add the token to the ajax's data :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
 ......
data: {'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
........
```

Comment: This still causes a TokenMisconception (same error)

Comment: Do you use your meta's token to ajax headers?  See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request at zarpio's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `jQuery` you can call `Axios` directly and have this `automatic csrf injection`, with the following code:

```
var data = ['name' => 'Nikola', 'lastName' => 'Gavric'];
axios.post('/comments', data).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

EDIT: Complete example for axios is

```
$('#storeComment').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve form data
    var temp = [];
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(index, field) {
        temp[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    // Post request with temp as data
    axios.post('/comments', temp).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
    });
});
```

And this is the code for `jQuery`, use whichever approach you like better:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/comments',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            'name': 'Nikola',
            'lastName': 'Gavric'
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          ........
            headers: {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
           }    
         ...........
  });
```

try this...

Answer (score 0):

Add `csrf-token` to head of your application :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then :

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some/url',
  type: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  success: function(res){
      // Your result
      console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to disable CSRF verification on specific route in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
 protected $except = ['/comments'];
```

Comment: Do not disable csrf protection, find the underlying cause for the token error.

Comment: Devon I don't know if you are aware that the call question owner asked for is obviously an API call. API calls by default should be put inside of CSRF exclusion, can you please elaborate your downvotes. Thanks

Comment: The reason for this is whoever is using your API doesn't know CSRF token and doesn't have to know it, thus all API urls are excluded from the CSRF checks

Comment: @NikolaGavric, I do not see anywhere that this is an "api" call.  No api token is being passed.  All post requests need some sort of token to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comment: I do because he is not serving any HTML content, but rather `application/json` which indicates it's an `ajax` call which further indicates it must be an `API` call and not a `web` call @Devon

Comment: @NikolaGavric that makes no difference in this context.  The fact that the user is not passing any token suggests they are using an authenticated session.  APIs still require a token.  Otherwise an attacker can force them to post comments on their behalf by posting to the same url with xss or from another site.