# how to pass named route parameter with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I need to pass route parameter with `ajax` but I am using named route method in `ajax` code.

route I want to go 
**Route**

```
Route::post('/edit/{id}', 'ArticleController@updateArticle')->name('updateArticle');
```

**Ajax**

```
var id= $("input[name=editId]").val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url:"{{ route('updateArticle',"id") }}",
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

I want to use variable `id` in `ajax` URL.

Comment: is this ajax function in a `blade` file?

Comment: yes,in a blade file

Comment: Don't Write Ajax code in blade its bad practice.Write it in JavaScript file and load it in your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, just change your ajax url with this one.

```
var id= $("input[name=editId]").val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url:"{{ route('updateArticle') }}" + '/' + id,
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: This shows error that says "Missing required parameter".

Answer (score 13):

Try to use replace function:

```
var id = $("input[name=editId]").val();
var url = "{{ route('updateArticle', ":id") }}";
url = url.replace(':id', id);

$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url: url,
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: It's really awesome

Comment: Man you're a life saver

Comment: WOW ! Too good !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Put  `+` around `id` variable and make sure you are passing X-CSRF-Token via `formdata` variable or try sending [manualy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32738930/9501353) :**

replace this line :

> url:"{{ route('updateArticle',"id") }}",

with this :

> url:"{{ route('updateArticle',"+id+") }}",

```
var id= $("input[name=editId]").val();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url:"{{ route('updateArticle',"+id+") }}",
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: your code works..i forgot X-CSRF. thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: My url get +id+ not the id

Answer (score 0):

```js
Try this:
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { 
    var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
    var id= $(this).val();
    var url = '{{ route("student.destroy_academic_qualifications", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data:{
            _token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(dataResult){
            var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
            if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                $ele.fadeOut().remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this.

In your blade file

```
<script>
window.your_route = "{{ route('updateArticle',['id'=>$id]) }}";
</script>
```

In you JavaScript you can use created variable.

```
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url:window.your_route,
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this below, just hardcode the url and id

```
var id= $("input[name=editId]").val();

$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   url:"edit/1",
   data: formdata,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data){
        $('.alert-success').html(data.success).fadeIn('slow');
        $('.alert-success').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: but the id is dynamic

Answer (score -1):

> in form

```
 <form id="form-create-role" action="{{route('role-create')}}" >
```

> in file role-create.js

```
 $(function(){
  
  $('#form-create-role').submit(function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        
      }
    });
    
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

**I do this by two ways**

1. By using full url

```
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(){
    let contactId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.location.origin + "/view-contact-details/" + contactId,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

2. By using named route parameter

```
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(){
    let contactId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let url = "{{ route('view.contact', ['id' => ":contactId"]) }}";
    url = url.replace(":contactId", contactId);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

You can use any of these :)

Answer (score -1):

```
"{{ route('teacher.guideline', '') }}"+"/"+data.teacher_id
```

This will definitely work.