# CSRF token issues with multiple ajax calls

Tags: laravel, csrf

I have a laravel page that allows users to save a search but only if they are logged in. They can log in with no problem or save a search with no problem, the CSRF token is accepted. However, if the user has to log in and then save a search I get the "CSRF token mismatch." error.

I'm assuming that a new token is generated on each post or database update but not sure. Should I be retrieving a new CSRF token after the post to the controller and then updating the CSRF inputs on the page?

I've tried with this in my header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and also using this in my forms

```
@csrf
```

and then in my ajax calls

```
var token    = $('[name=_token]').val();
```

The token is being passed in the parameters so I know it is there but will only work on the first ajax call

Comment: Hey @xjx424 ! Are you able to share some of the code that you're working with?

Comment: I've updated my question with some code

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I'm assuming you've read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) about adding the token to all request headers?

Comment: Yes, tried that too. It keeps passing the same token each time via data or the header. Does the token value change after any posts?

Comment: I believe it's per user session, so shouldn't change between post requests

Comment: I didn't think so. Do you know of a way to retrieve the token? I tried via ajax but I can't view the results from the controller because the token mismatch error shows every time.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request/57050708) answer on SO - let me know if perhaps that solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen that post. I've probably seen every SO related question over the past 4 hours :)

Comment: Are you logging in using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're getting the data from **ajax**, but the `token` variable you have assigned may not be getting the right data.  At least not if your `meta` above is what is setting it.

You might try changing your `token` setting using the `content` attrib, not `val()` as follows (IE test removing from the form and use the token you set in the meta):

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

The other thing to check is how you are placing that into your **ajax**.  I find it works best when set into the **ajax** headers in a base file higher up than your **ajax** - calling the headers outside the current **ajax** call will usually resolve the issue of a `csrf mismatch` as you are having.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved an urgent support call! Just for a while! Maybe not the best way, but that time it worked!

First, I created a javascript function to update the token:

```
function renewToken() {
    var csrfUrl = $("meta[name='url_page']").attr('content') + '/refresh_csrf';

    $.get(csrfUrl, function (data) {
        $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', data);
    });
    return;
 }
```

So I created this route:

```
Route::get('/refresh_csrf', function () {
    return response()->json(csrf_token());
})->name('csrf.renew')->middleware('auth'); /* Test */
```

Because, when the token expired before each new ajax request, the blade still continued having an old token. But, this function was used to update the token before each ajax request.

For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open_modal', function () {
   renewToken();
   var group_id = $(this).val();

   $.get(url + '/' + group_id, function (data) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was left over line of code from a test that was refreshing the session, stupid mistake on my part.