# Laravel 419 Error using Ajax and formData,

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, serialization

My form data doesn't send any thing i don't know why i tried to debug line by line and i found the problem in `data: formData` variabe, can someone help me :

also i can't stop redirection using return false

```
$(function(){
// When Form #xhr is Submited
$('#xhr').submit(function(){
    var selectedFile = null;
    var data = new FormData();

    //if(selectedFile !== null)
    data.append('image', selectedFile, selectedFile.name)

    $($(form).serializeArray()).each(function(i, field){ 
        data.append(field.name, field.value);
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.success);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
    });
```

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request)

Answer (score 1):

use serialize for collecting data

```
var formData = $('form').serializeArray(),


$.ajax({
    url: $("#myform").attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
        alert("yes");
    }
});
```

for token add this in your html

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then before sending ajax request set this

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

$.ajax({
    url: $("#myform").attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(){
        alert("yes");
    }
});
```

example:

file:index.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="myform">
        <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        <input type="text" name="second" id="second">
        <input type="text" name="third" id="third">
        <button type="button" id="mysubmitbutton">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
       $("body").on("click", "#mysubmitbutton", function () {
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf- token"]').attr('content')          }
        });


       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "{{ route('myRouteName') }}",
           data: {
                    'first': $("#first").val(),
                    'second': $("#second").val(),
                    'third': $("#third").val()
                 },
           success: function (msg) {
               alert('wooow');
           }
        });
    });
     </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

in this simple example i set csrf token in header then when user click on button i collect data and send ajax request

Comment: already i have the serialization,  the problem is in token ( laravel )

Comment: i update my answer i forgot to import jquery in example sorry. its simple just add <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> to your html head and use ajaxSetup befor actual sending ajax request

Comment: Thank you i fixed the issue but i don't know why i can't stop my form redirection since i have used return false; please check i will update my question

Comment: please check again, return false doesn't block my form redirection, it's like i'm not using ajax or there is an issue

Comment: that is because probably you set submit button inside the form tag or your button type is submit

Comment: it's normal to be inside form no ?

Comment: yes but when you put it inside form tag html do the redirection or if you are going to set it inside the form tag set the button type to button <button type="button">submit</button>