# I am getting anCSRF token mismatch exception in Safari on Laravel 7.X when I post a form request using window.open

Tags: php, laravel, safari

When I try to post a form request using window.open script, it will cause csrf token mismatch exception in Safari on Laravel 7.X. I've tested Chrome and Firefox and they're just fine. Safari also works perfectly with same code on Laravel 6.18.16.

#### Environments

- Laravel Version: 7.13.0
- PHP Version: 7.2.31
- Database Driver & Version: n/a
- macOS: 10.15.5
- Safari: 13.1.1
- Chrome: 83.0.4103.61
- Firefox: 76.0.1

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Install a fresh laravel app

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel popup7
```

2. web.php

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/blank', function () {
    return 'blank page';
});
```

3. welcome.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <script>
            function openPopup(target) {
                window.open("", target + "_popup", "width=430,height=640,scrollbar=yes");
                let form = document.getElementById(target);
                form.target = target + "_popup";
                form.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="mobile" name="mobile" action="/blank" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <button onclick="openPopup('mobile');">
            open
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

4. click 'open' button
   [image]

#### Additional Information

There is no proper cookie header for `/blank` request on Laravel 7.X

**request/response header for `/blank` in Safari on Laravel 7.X**
- request

[image: request image]

- response

[image: response image]

**request/response header for `/blank` in Safari on Laravel 6.18.16**
- request

[image: request image]

- response

[image: response image]

Answer (score 0):

Window.open is a `GET` request and without considering it's request method `window.open` can't carry your csrf token since csrf token is encrypted and stored in session so what you can do is to send an ajax request 
Maybe this post can help you [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request)

Comment: Thanks for your help @AH.Pooladvand . But window.open doesn't have any url, and it submit a `POST` form request. Other browser works normally except Safari.