# TokenMismatchException on VerifyCsrfToken.php:53

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, csrf

On laravel.log I get this:

```
[2020-08-20 15:51:08] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/ialinves/public_html/cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:53
```

On browser console I get this:

```
POST https://ial.pt/ajaxform 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    
    var nom = 'teste';
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajaxform',
        data: /*JSON.stringify({name: nom})*/{},
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On the head I have:

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I've tried to comment csrf on Kernel.php and when I did it it worked...
I have also added route group to the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
//Form routes
Route::post('ajaxform', 'formulariosController@contacts');
```

});

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Comment: @Magiczne Already did ...

Comment: Have you tried sending token with the data?
Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Additionally, you can try setting X-Requested-With header to XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Magiczne I've already tried that aswell, const VERSION = '5.1.45 (LTS)';

Comment: I've installed Laravel 5.1.45 and included tha same jquery code and everything works fine.

Are you sure that JS script reads correct value from meta tag?

Comment: @Magiczne Yes I am sure, because I copied that from another app on the same version and everything works fine aswell.