# My Laravel website application shows "CSRF MISMATCH" every time why?

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf

CSRF token mismatch in laraval 8, token code added to meta tag and this simple ajax not working,

[image]

Comment: show some code where you get error like ajax code ,route for that request etc..

Comment: function runtest()
{
var id="1";
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {"_token": token,"id": id},
url: "{{url('some_url')}}",
success: function(msg){
// do whatever you want with the response 
}
});
}

Comment: above shows ajax code

Comment: Is that the answer you're looking for? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Comment: once you try clearing  php artisan view:clear  then php artisan key:generate and then serve again.i have tried your ajax and it works expected so

Comment: also verifiy by alerting token whether you get value or not

Comment: both clear view  and key regenerated done,  but ""message": "CSRF token mismatch.",

Comment: yes,   also verifiy by alerting token whether you get value or not = >  value showing

Comment: Hello, please remember to post code as text rather than pictures.  Details about the reasons why are in this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

Add headers key after success key:

```
        success: function(msg){
           //do whatever you want with the response
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
```

and in views\layouts\app.blade.php add this line:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: thanks all,   its now working after clear all cache ,view,and config

Answer (score 0):

Add headers key after success key:

```
    success: function(msg){
       //do whatever you want with the response
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
```

and in views\layouts\app.blade.php add this line: