# Laravel: "CSRF token mismatch.", on right code

Tags: ajax, laravel

Everything was working fine. No issue. But suddenly from nowhere this error started to show up.

```
"CSRF token mismatch.",
```

All forms was working fine and next day I open project and found this error. Very strange, how a working code started to show error all of the sudden...!!

Here is my code

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"{{ route('loginuser.post') }}",
    data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",email:email,password:password,remember:remember},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
```

As you can see here is I am adding csrf token in this line

```
data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",email:email,password:password,remember:remember},
```

I try to clear cache too but still didn't work. How a working code can do like this all of the sudden. Laravel is surely a strange framework!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request

Comment: maybe it's because your "data"  json object is broken.

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya Solution given in your linked post, I have already used in my code. See my post, second code line, here I mentioned.

Comment: @N69S How is this? What can I do about it?

Comment: Did you try to clear the sessions in addition to the cache?

Comment: replace it with `{"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","email":email,"password":password,"remember":remember}`

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I did, using php artisan commands in powerShell.

Comment: @N69S STill same error

Comment: Try it in incognito as well  or in a different browser. If it's still not working then check if sessions are created successfully on the server

Comment: @apokryfos Nothing works. But when I try to move project from local to live server then it worked. I mean, this issue only coming in localhost.

Comment: Is a session being created in localhost? What is your session driver?

Comment: @apokryfos Session is not created. I can't go to login restricted page.

Comment: If session is not created then (if using a file session driver) check if the www user has permission to write to the sessions folder (usually storage/framework/sessions) or if you're using a different driver take troubleshooting steps based on that

Comment: @apokryfos I found the solution. It seems cache problem (don't know how). But when I try to run form in other browser then it started to work. What exactly cause it, still a mystery to me